# Form in Bootstrap modal not posting PHP values to another page

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a form in a bootstrap modal window to post data to another page. However when i try to print the post values on the other page all I am getting is an empty array.

Here's my modal code:

```
<div class="modal hide" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
            X</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">
            Enter your Credentials</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    <form id="modal-form" class="form-horizontal" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="POST" action="login.php" data-remote="true">
    <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
    <div class="controls">
    <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Password</label>
    <div class="controls">
    <input type="password" id="passwd" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
    <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
    </label>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit"/>
    <a href="register" class="btn btn-primary">Sign up</a> 
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>          
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the command I'm giving in login.php:

```
echo "Email is:";
echo $_POST["email"];
echo "Password is:";
echo $_POST["passwd"];
```

However all I'm getting is an empty array.

Is there some sort of special way I'm supposed to do this?

Comment: you need the attribute `name` in the <input id="email" name="email"..

Comment: edit this: <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">

Comment: wow that was so simple thanks! I was under the impression that this was happening using the id.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have't define name in input just change two line from your code. add name of that input.

```
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
<input type="password" id="passwd" name="passwd" placeholder="Password" />
```